# Docker Compose: Google Authentication Creds DNS

Tags: docker-compose, google-api, dns, airflow, google-oauth

**Problem:**

I am attempting to have a containerized environment for Airflow setup using Docker Compose and within this environment I am attempting to have Google Credentials be refreshed as needed based on them expiring. The gist of the work can be found through the following link to [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python).

This code has been re-worked in an attempt to have it be able to run in a production environment in Airflow so that each time the token has been determined as expired it will refresh said token. The relevant portion of this code with needed imports is below.

```py
import logging
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

  def build_service(self, scope=None, token_path=None, credential_path=None):
    """Handles authentication of API.

    Params are optional and default to `None`, deferring to `self.param_name`.

    Args:
    scope: stores users access and refresh tokens for working with
        google sheets
    token_path: file path to store of users access and refresh
        tokens for working with google sheets
    """
    scope = scope or self.scope
    token_path = token_path or self.token_path
    credential_path = credential_path or self.credential_path

    try:
      if type(token_path) == 'str':
        logging.info('Attempting token from user authored file...')
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(token_path, scope)
      elif type(token_path) == dict:
        logging.info('Attempting token from user provided dict...')
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_info(token_path, scope)
    except Exception as e:
      creds = None
      logging.info(e)

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
      if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
```

The above works just fine from my local terminal when attempting to run, but when I run it within Airflow in an attempt to test the resulting errors are ones that seem to describe DNS errors...or at least that's what I believe. Please see below for a collection of these.

```py
[2023-05-23 14:33:01,021] {taskinstance.py:1150} ERROR - HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fab3772d470>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname',))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 61, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 978, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 309, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 172, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fab3772d470>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 446, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fab3772d470>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 194, in __call__
    method, url, data=body, headers=headers, timeout=timeout, **kwargs
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fab3772d470>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname',))
```

I attempted to navigate around these issues by changing the used DNS within my containerized environment to be 8.8.8.8. This worked in a sense that I was now able to, when exec'd into the containers, run the above code to retrieve a refreshed token. What happened now though is that none of my other DAGs run and none of them generate logs when DAGs are scheduled to run. Docker Compose file below.

```
version: '3.9'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  image: apache/airflow:1.10.15
  environment:
    - AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR=CeleryExecutor
    - AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    - AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND=db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    - AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL=redis://:@redis:6379/0
    - AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY=FB0o_zt4e3Ziq3LdUUO7F2Z95cvFFx16hU8jTeR1ASM=
    - AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION=True
    - AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_DEFAULT_CONNECTIONS=False
    - AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__DAG_DIR_LIST_INTERVAL=30
  volumes:
    - ./scripts:/opt/airflow/scripts
    - ./airflow-data/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./airflow-data/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - ./airflow-data/config:/opt/airflow/config
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ${DAGS_SOURCE}/generic_functions:/opt/airflow/dags/generic_functions
    - ${DAGS_SOURCE}/other_functions:/opt/airflow/dags/other_functions
    - ${DAGS_SOURCE}/sr_functions:/opt/airflow/dags/sr_functions
    - ${DAGS_SOURCE}:/opt/airflow/dags-source
  dns:
    - 8.8.8.8

networks:
  airflow:

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.1
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
      - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    command: >
     postgres
       -c listen_addresses=*
       -c logging_collector=on
       -c log_destination=stderr
       -c max_connections=200
    networks:
      - airflow
  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.5
    environment:
      REDIS_HOST: redis
      REDIS_PORT: 6379
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - airflow
  webserver:
    << : *airflow-common
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 8s
        max_attempts: 3
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    entrypoint: ./scripts/webserver.sh
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /opt/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
    networks:
      - airflow
  flower:
    << : *airflow-common
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    depends_on:
      - redis
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 8s
        max_attempts: 3
    command: flower
    networks:
      - airflow
  scheduler:
    << : *airflow-common
    entrypoint: ./scripts/scheduler.sh
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 8s
        max_attempts: 3
    networks:
      - airflow
  worker:
    << : *airflow-common
    entrypoint: ./scripts/worker.sh
    depends_on:
      - scheduler
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 8s
        max_attempts: 3
    networks:
      - airflow
  initdb:
    << : *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 8s
        max_attempts: 5
    command: -c "airflow db init"
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
    networks:
      - airflow
```

My expectation was that when altering the DNS command within the Docker Compose file that it would allow everything to work seamlessly, but now none of the other DAGSs within my containerized environment will run. Just unsure of what my next steps might be here to alter the Docker Compose file in order to allow for the Refresh Creds to work here.